# Python environment is not changing

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have followed some guidance on how to indicate Python 3 to run on Visual Studio Code in my Linux machine. However when I execute my script it gives me an error with path indicating Python 2.7

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

I don't know if I configure something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set python 3 as default on the system by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

Comment: It still uses the old path. Do I need to restart my machine?

Comment: restart not required for linux, however, you may require to close existing console/IDE and open a new console wherever you are testing.